# Convert a vector of u8 bytes into a rust_decimal

Tags: rust, decimal

I am loading data from another language. Numbers can be very large and they are serialized as a byte array of u8s.

These are loaded into rust as a vec of u8s:

`vec![1, 0, 0]`

This represents 100. I also have a u32 to represent the cale.

I'm trying to load this into a rust_decimal, but am stuck.

measure_value.value -> a vec of u8
measure_value.scale -> a u32

```
let r_dec = rust_Decimal::????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the implementation I have so far, but it feels inelegant!

```
pub fn proto_to_decimal(input: &DecimalValueProto) -> Result<Decimal, String> {
    let mut num = 0;
    let mut power: i32 = (input.value.len() - 1)
        .try_into()
        .map_err(|_| "Failed to convert proto to decimal")?; //casting down from usize to i32 is failable

    for digit in input.value.iter() {
        let expansion: i128 = if power == 0 { expansion = *digit as i128 } else { expansion = (*digit as i128) * 10_i128.pow(power as u32) as i128 }
        num += expansion;
        power -= 1;
    }
    Ok(Decimal::from_i128_with_scale(num as i128, input.scale))
}
```

Comment: Tip: `if` can return values, so you can do `let expansion = if  ...` and this eliminates both the pre-declared `let mut` and the inner `expansion =` parts.

Comment: While there's certainly room for improvement on this implementation, if it works that's a great start. One thing to consider is making this an `impl From<&DecimalValueProto> for Decimal` if you can, as that's more Rust-like.

Comment: @tadman - mind giving me the example? I'm super new to rust!

Also thanks re: the From<&T> tip!

Comment: Think of Rust's `if` as having all the power of a ternary as in `a = x ? y : z` becomes `let a = if x { y } else { z }`. Can greatly reduce how much code you need to write.